# Using an 'is' expression when the right-hand operand is a variable?

Tags: dart

I am trying to write a function that takes two arguments: `givenType` and `targetType`. If these two arguments match, I want `givenType` to be returned, otherwise `null`.

For this objective, I am trying to utilize Dart's `is` expression (maybe there is a better way to go about it, I am open to suggestions). Initially, I thought it would be as simple as writing this:

```
matchesTarget(givenType, targetType) {
 if (givenType is targetType) {
   return givenType;
 }

  return null;
}
```

But this produces an error:

> The name 'targetType' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is'
>   expression. Try correcting the name to match an existing
>   type.dart(type_test_with_non_type)

I tried looking up what satisfies an `is` expression but cannot seem to find it in the documentation. It seems like it needs its right-hand operand to be known at compile-time (hoping this is wrong, but it does not seem like I can use a variable), but if so, how else can I achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant guess the purpose of the function (or the scenario where it would be used, so if you can clarify it would be great). First of all, I don't know if you are passing "types" as arguments. And yes, you need to specify in compile time the right hand argument of the `is` function.

Meanwhile, if you are passing types, with one change, you can check if the types passed to your function at runtime.

```dart
matchesTarget(Type givenType, Type targetType) {
  print('${givenType.runtimeType} ${targetType.runtimeType}');
 if (givenType == targetType) {
   return givenType;
 }
  return null;
}

main(){
    var a = int; //this is a Type
    var b = String; //this is also a Type

    print(matchesTarget(a,b)); //You are passing different Types, so it will return null

    var c = int; //this is also a Type

    print(matchesTarget(a,c)); //You are passing same Types, so it will return int
}
```

But if you are passing variables, the solution is pretty similar:

```dart
matchesTarget(givenVar, targetVar) {
  print('${givenVar.runtimeType} ${targetVar.runtimeType}');
 if (givenVar.runtimeType == targetVar.runtimeType) {
   return givenVar.runtimeType;
 }
  return null;
}

main(){
    var a = 10; //this is a variable (int)
    var b = "hello"; //this is also a variable (String)

    print(matchesTarget(a,b)); //this will return null

    var c = 12; //this is also a variable (int)

    print(matchesTarget(a,c)); //this will return int
}
```

### The Final Answer

```dart
matchesTarget(givenVar, targetType) {
  print('${givenVar.runtimeType} ${targetType}');
 if (givenVar.runtimeType == targetType) {
   return givenVar;
 }
  return null;
}

main(){
    var a = 10; //this is a variable (int)
    var b = String; //this is a type (String)

    print(matchesTarget(a,b)); //this will return null because 'a' isnt a String

    var c = int; //this is also a type (int)

    print(matchesTarget(a,c)); //this will return the value of 'a' (10)
}
```

Comment: The fault likely lies in the way I described the question. The point of this function is `givenType` for lack of a better name (maybe `givenObj` would be better?), is an instance of some type, meanwhile, `targetType` is what is needed. If `givenType` is of type `targetType`, then I want it returned. Otherwise null.

Comment: I will edit my answer with a third option that matches your requirements :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `as`, `is`, and `is!` operators are handy for checking types at runtime.
The `is` operator in Dart can be only used for type checking and not checking if two values are equal.

The result of `obj is T` is `true` if `obj` implements the interface specified by `T`. For example, `obj is Object` is always `true`.

See the below code for an example of how to use the `is` operator

```
if (emp is Person) {
  // Type check
  emp.firstName = 'Bob';
}
```

Even the error message that you're getting says that

> The name 'targetType' isn't a type and can't be used in an 'is'
>   expression.

So the bottomline is that you can use `is` only for checking if a variable or value belongs to a particular data type.

For checking equality, you can use the `==` operator if comparing primitive types, or write your own method for comparing the values. Hope this helps!